# Webcontrols from a repeater control loose their value

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, asprepeater

It seams that the solution for this problem would be what it is said in this post: http://codinglifestyle.wordpress.com/2009/10/08/repeaters-and-lost-data-after-postback-viewstate/ however it seams that for me does not work :|

So I have a page and in that page a repeater that has 3 webcontrols.

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="repFissaggio" runat="server" OnItemCreated="repFissaggio_ItemCreated" EnableViewState="true" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:30%;border: gray 1px solid;">
                    <div style="text-align: center; width:100%; border-right: gray 1px solid; border-top: gray 1px solid; border-left: gray 1px solid;border-bottom: gray 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;    FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12px; background-color:gainsboro;">Disegno Articolo</div>
                    <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetFileAddress(Container.DataItem) %>' Width='220px' ID="imgDisegnoArt"  EnableViewState="false"></asp:Image>
                </td>
                <td style="width:65%">
                    <div style="text-align: center; width:100%; border-right: gray 1px solid; border-top: gray 1px solid; border-left: gray 1px solid;border-bottom: gray 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;    FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12px; background-color:gainsboro;">Informazioni Articolo</div>
                    <gsc:SchSolettoFinissaggioArticoloUC ID="ucSchSolettoFinissaggioArticolo" runat="server"></gsc:SchSolettoFinissaggioArticoloUC>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="border: gray 1px solid;">
                    <div style="text-align: center; width:100%; border-right: gray 1px solid; border-top: gray 1px solid; border-left: gray 1px solid;border-bottom: gray 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;    FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12px; background-color:gainsboro;">Schema Finissaggio</div>
                    <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetFileAddress(Container.DataItem) %>' Width='220px' ID="imgSchedaFissaggio" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Image>
                    <asp:Label ID="divfileName" runat="server" Text='<%# GetFileName(Container.DataItem) %>' style="text-align: center; width:100%"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <fieldset  style="padding: 10px,10px,10px,10px; border-bottom-width: 5px">
                        <legend>Sistema di Industrializzazione</legend>
                        <gsc:SchSolettoSistemaProdIndusUC ID="ucSchSolettoSistemaIndus" runat="server"></gsc:SchSolettoSistemaProdIndusUC>
                    </fieldset>
                    <br />
                    <fieldset  style="padding: 10px,10px,10px,10px; border-bottom-width: 5px">
                    <legend>Sistema di Produzione</legend>
                        <gsc:SchSolettoSistemaProdIndusUC ID="ucSchSolettoSistemaProd" runat="server"></gsc:SchSolettoSistemaProdIndusUC>
                    </fieldset>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

On init I call this method

```
 protected override void InitEditor()
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ...
                repFissaggio.DataSource = SolettoDS.SoleXSchTec;
                repFissaggio.DataBind();
            }

        }
```

Above this repeater I have other webcontrols. When I change a value of a dropdown the form is submitted. When that happens values of webcontrol from repeater looses their value.
What do you suggest to do?
Thanks.

Comment: You can try removing if(!IsPostBack) condition to bind repeater every time (also after PostBack), but make sure IDs of all your inputs (inside webcontrols) are the same, so the values could be successfully retrieved from the post data and viewstate.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I found the answer: I should put binding in  protected void repFissaggio_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) and not in repFissaggio_ItemCreated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: I should put binding in protected void repFissaggio_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) and not in repFissaggio_ItemCreated